# Xml in Insert causing Fatal error of '?xml' must be defined

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, mysql.data, dbup

While running through 3rd party NuGet Package called DbUp

```
INSERT INTO `portalquery` 
VALUES 
(31,'update portal.Config_PropertyValues set value = \''<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\r\n<data></fata>\'' where engineid = \''@engineid\'' and PropertyID = \''459\'';'',''Set Demograhpics node refresh interval to \''1\''',NULL,NULL,6)
```

I am getting following error:

```
Script block number: 12; Error code -2147467259; Message: Fatal error encountered during command execution.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Parameter '?xml' must be defined.
```

I know what the issue is here but I am not able to escape "?" mark no matter what I do.

Comment: query looking little confusing, just to clarify its an update query inside insert query that stores in column for later use

Comment: Get it working with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Server.  the error message are much better in SSMS than VS.

Comment: It would help if you can post what exactly are you trying to insert, without added escape characters.

Comment: @OctoCode this is what I want to insert in column

'update portal.Config_PropertyValues set value = \''<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\r\n<data></fata>\'' where engineid = \''@engineid\'' and PropertyID = \''459\'';'

Comment: Your problem, as you can see from the syntax highlighting in the code you've posted, is that you're escaping the quote wrong: `\'` is an escaped quote then the next `'` closes the string, meaning `<?xml` is no longer part of the string.

Comment: (I realise this is a very old question, but someone's just brought it back to the front page by posting a spam answer.)